# Encrypting file using GnuPG on command line hangs forever

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

There is one file I want to encrypt with GnuPG by

```
    gpg2 --homedir=~/.gnupg --always-trust=true --recipient="BlahBlah" --encrypt=/path/to/file --output=/path/to/output_file
```

However this command seems to hang forever and never return. Interestingly, after I interrupt process, there is indeed `/path/to/output_file` created , however the bytes written there is much bigger than raw payload (for example my `/path/to/file` is only of 5 bytes but it turns out there are nearly 200 bytes written to `/path/to/output_file`).

There must be something wrong, but I really couldn't figure out what is it.

I have in advance imported the key for `BlahBlah` by `gpg --import key.asc`. It happens both for GnuPG 1 and GnuPG 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're applying `--encrypt` in a wrong way. `--encrypt` does not expect any parameters, the file(s) to be worked on are passed as very last arguments. Additionally, following the documentation you should pass `--output /path/to/output_file` instead of `--output=/path/to/output_file`. Finally, GnuPG distinguishes between options and commands, and options should precede commands.

What you observe is that GnuPG starts writing header information, but then waits for input from STDIN (until interrupted).

The GnuPG command line you're looking for is

```
gpg2 --homedir=~/.gnupg --always-trust=true --recipient="BlahBlah" --output /path/to/output_file --encrypt /path/to/file
```

One last hint: the combination of `--always-trust=true` and resolving a recipient by user ID is a very bad idea, as any other key with the same user ID in the local keyring might be used. Pass the full key's fingerprint instead, which specifically selects a distinct key ([using short key IDs is not secure, either](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837)).